# What is required for a minimum viable Bell test experiment at home?

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-entanglement, home-experiment, experimental-technique, bells-inequality

My objective is to create a tabletop Bell test experimental setup generating data of suitable quality for undergraduate education or satisfaction of personal curiosity; remaining free from loopholes or pushing fidelity frontiers is not a concern.

As has been [covered elsewhere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/544349/182854) you need to be able to emit & detect single photons in order to measure quantum phenomena. You can buy the single-photon double-slit experimental setup "in a box" [from TeachSpin](https://www.teachspin.com/two-slit) for about $9500, which uses (basically) a dim lightbulb behind a filter to generate few enough photons that only one photon is likely to be flying through the apparatus at any given time. However, I suspect this would not be good enough for Bell test where you need to correlate photon emission & detection. What is the minimal experimental setup necessary for a basic Bell test experiment, and approximately how much would it cost? Thousands? Tens of thousands?

The only heralded single-photon emitter I can find online [costs $22,000](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_ID=13675) by itself, but I suspect that price is more a function of convenience, quality, and niche market. I would expect to have to build one myself through a laser, SPDC crystal, and detector. In a [similar unanswered question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/120010/is-there-a-cheap-way-i-can-do-a-bell-inequality-experiment) a user claims in a comment that a basic working Bell test experiment can be conducted "for cheap" (presumably a few thousand dollars). Has
anyone considered this problem?

A [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11465/the-most-price-efficient-experimental-setup-involving-spdc-single-photon-counti) concerns the price of components giving specific capabilities but does not cover a full Bell test experimental setup.

Comment: I think you're going to want entangled photon pairs, not just single photons...

Comment: There is now an educational lab product claiming to demonstrate entanglement, but the price is only available by inquiry: https://qutools.com/qued/

Comment: @ahelwer have you inquired? What have you heard? ;)

Comment: @Cheng in the range of mid-\$10ks, up into the low \$100ks depending on what setup you want.